# AJAX + Hebrew letters

Tags: ajax, hebrew

I send by XMLRequest Hebrew letters to Servlet, at xmlRequest it's still Hebrew, in servlet I receive weird letters,.Java works on Unicode how to convert letters from textarea to Unicode t send to servlet

Answer (score 3):

Does your XMLRequest specify charset? That's a common source of character mangling.

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
```